# Printing page numbers using Pisa

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, pisa

I am using pisa in my django project, to make my html generate on a PDF for report functionality.  Some of my reports are getting rather large and I have noticed it doesn't have any page numbering on it.  Does anyone know how I can get page numbers to show up on the printed PDF report?

**edit**

here is how I generate the PDF

```
if request.POST.has_key('print_report_submit'):
            context['show_report'] = True
            context['mb_logo'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../media/images/mb_logo.jpg")
            html = render_to_string('reports/fam_maturity_print.html', RequestContext(request,context))
            result = StringIO.StringIO()
            pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
            response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=family_maturity-statement.pdf'
            return response
```

**HTML**

```
{% if show_report %}

<table width="100%">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" width="400px">
            <h1 class="title">Family Maturities by Year</h1>
            <br/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="500px">
            <img src="{{ mb_logo }}"/>
        <td>                            <p>
              <img style="max-height: 60px; max-width:60px;" src="{{ check_image }}"/>
          </p>
    </tr>
</table>
    <br/>
    <br/>



   <hr class="report_hr1"/>
   <h2 class="state_head" style="font-size: 16px;">Statement Information As of {{ statement_date|date:"F d, Y" }}</h2>
<hr class="report_hr1"/>

    <table>

    {% for plan_dict in plan_list %}
        <hr class="report_hr2"/>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Plan Holder: </strong></td><td>{{ plan_dict.plan.get_primary_owner.member.client}}</td>
            <td><strong>Joint Owner(s): </strong></td>
            <td>
                {% for member in plan_dict.plan.planmember_set.all %}
                    {% ifnotequal member.ownership_type.code "primary" %}
                        {{ member }}
                    {% endifnotequal %}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Plan ID: </strong></td><td>{{ plan_dict.plan.id }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Plan type: </strong></td><td>{{ plan_dict.plan.plan_type }}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <hr class="report_hr2"/>
        {#      This is the table for the current year's maturities      #}
        {% if plan_dict.investment %}
        <table>
            <td colspan="2"><h3>{{ cur_year }}</h3></td>
            <tr>
                <th>Financial Institution</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Principal</th>
                <th>Maturity</th>
            </tr>
            {% for i in plan_dict.investment %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ i.financial_institution.abbr }}</td>
                <td>{{ i.product.code }}</td>
                <td>${{ i.amount|intcomma }}</td>
                <td>${{ i.maturity_amount|intcomma }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                    <td><strong>Total for {{ cur_year }}</strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong>${{ plan_dict.total|intcomma }}</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>${{ plan_dict.total_m|intcomma }}</strong></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        {% endif %}
        <div id="holding_table" align="center">
               <h3>Holding Totals with Each Company</h3>
               <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Financial Institution</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Total</td>
                    </tr>
               {% for l in plan_dict.total_list %}
                   {% if l.maturity_amount__sum != None %}
                       <tr>
                        <td>{{ l.financial_institution__abbr }}</td>
                        <td>${{ l.maturity_amount__sum|intcomma }}</td>
                    </tr>
                   {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Total Non-Fund Holdings for this plan</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">${{ plan_dict.grand|intcomma }}</td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
                <span class="disclaimer_span">This report has been prepared from data believed to be reliable but no
                        representation is made as to accuracy or completeness.</span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>

    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How says in this link:

http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/501-Pisa-and-Reportlab-pitfalls.html

> One problem I ran into was adding a static footer to my pages, which contains a `<pdf:pagenumber />` tag and should show the current pagenumber at the bottom of every page of the resulting PDF. The problem was, that every page just showed the number 0. The solution was very simple, but I was only able to figure it out after studiying the pisa source-code: You can only use the  tag inside a paragraph, not (as I did) inside a table for example. Even parapgraphs inside tables don't work. It has to be a top-level paragraph.

Edit

Try this:

```
<div>
   <pdf:pagenumber />
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so I tried this on my html which gets printed `<p><pdf:pagenumber /></p>` and nothing still shows up?

Comment: How are you generating your pdf?

Comment: I don't see you are using <p><pdf:pagenumber /></p> and remember the link: "You can only use the tag inside a paragraph, not (as I did) inside a table for example. Even parapgraphs inside tables don't work. It has to be a top-level paragraph."

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot to include that... it still doesnt work tho

Comment: Are you sure you tag <pdf:pagenumber> is not inside the table?

Comment: yes I am sure... I placed it right before the `{% endif %}` at the bottom of the template

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me you need to use this its for A3 size

```
@page{
        size: A3;
        margin: 1cm;

      @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
        left: 400pt; top: 1170pt; height: 20pt;
        
    }
    }
```

you have to put on above table

```
<div id="footer_content"> Page <pdf:pagenumber>
of <pdf:pagecount> </div>
```